# How does std::vector in c++ gets deallocated by default

Tags: c++, stl

I have read that, in c++ STL's vector gets deallocated as soon as the variable goes out of scope. So I tried going through STL's vector implementation, but it doesn't seem to be happening in the destructor of class vector, so how does deallocation happen or how is it being implemented.

Comment: It happens in the destructor of *something*. Either `vector` itself or one of its data members or one of its base class subobjects, depending on the implementation.

Comment: The memory is usually managed by a base class, for exception safety. See Stroustrup's [Exception Safety: Concepts and Techniques](https://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf) for a discussion of the issues and a small vector example.

Comment: Would you like to check this reimplementation of [Vector Container](https://github.com/CaglayanDokme/CPP-Exercises/blob/main/Containers/VectorContainer.h) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several STL implementations, they diff from each other, but they are similar. Let's take the latest version of GCC's [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h) as an example:

The destructor of `std::vector`, all the elements in the vector are destroyed via calling `std::_Destroy`

```cpp
      ~vector() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      {
    std::_Destroy(this->_M_impl._M_start, this->_M_impl._M_finish,
              _M_get_Tp_allocator());
    _GLIBCXX_ASAN_ANNOTATE_BEFORE_DEALLOC;
      }
```

The `vector` has a base class:

```cpp
  template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Tp> >
    class vector : protected _Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>
```

For the memory used in the vector itself, it is destroyed in `_M_deallocate` in the base class, which will call the `deallocate` at last:

```cpp
      ~_Vector_base() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      {
    _M_deallocate(_M_impl._M_start,
              _M_impl._M_end_of_storage - _M_impl._M_start);
      }
```

```cpp
      void
      deallocate(_Tp* __p, size_type __n __attribute__ ((__unused__)))
      {
#if __cpp_sized_deallocation
# define _GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(p, n) (p), (n) * sizeof(_Tp)
#else
# define _GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(p, n) (p)
#endif

#if __cpp_aligned_new
    if (alignof(_Tp) > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__)
      {
        _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE(_GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(__p, __n),
                     std::align_val_t(alignof(_Tp)));
        return;
      }
#endif
    _GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE(_GLIBCXX_SIZED_DEALLOC(__p, __n));
      }
```

`_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_DELETE` is a macro, we can regard it as `delete`

Answer (score 3):

The `std::vector` class's exact destruction place is left to implementation by spec.

But usually (when the vector goes out of scope), it should result in calling `std::allocator`'s `deallocate` method (which is `std::vector`'s second template-arg).
See also [What's the advantage of using `std::allocator` instead of new in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31358804/8740349)

Actually, remember that there is no rule for standard classes to be actual files (meaning you can ignore what you see there safely, as long as your code follows C++ standards, because those are part of compiler not C++).

Comment: The memory management of a `std::vector` is handled by its allocator, the second template argument. By default that's `std::allocator`, which does not use `malloc`/`free`.

Answer (score 2):

The vector's destructor destroys the dynamic memory and its content which the vector has created during its lifetime.

When the vector goes out of scope, its destructor is run automatically as part of its own destruction.

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that, in c++ STL's vector gets deallocated as soon as the variable goes out of scope.

Your search keywords are **object lifetime**, a variable's **scope** and **storage duration**.

This has nothing to do with `std::vector` specifically. If the control flow leaves the current scope, any object whose lifetime is bound to that scope (via automatic storage duration) is destroyed automatically.

For reference:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

---

> So I tried going through STL's vector implementation, but it doesn't seem to be happening in the destructor of class vector, so how does deallocation happen or how is it being implemented.

The standard library containers manage the memory they allocate and the objects they create via allocators. (But I believe that these details aren't really important for the general understanding of the basic functionality.)

For reference:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator
- [What's the advantage of using std::allocator instead of new in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358804/whats-the-advantage-of-using-stdallocator-instead-of-new-in-c)
- [Why does std::vector use std::allocator instead of operator new and delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436643/why-does-stdvector-use-stdallocator-instead-of-operator-new-and-delete)

Answer (score -1):

std::vector uses a **destructor** which calls `std::vector::_Tidy`
(MSVC implementation) on destruction (or deletion). This happens when the vector goes out of scope or if the vector is being destructed manually.