# Using std::vector from an object referenced by shared_ptr after shared_ptr's destruction

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, ros, stdvector

I apologise if the title is different from what I will be describing, I don't quite know how to describe it apart from using examples.

Suppose I have a `shared_ptr` of an object, and within that object, is a vector. I assign that vector to a variable so I can access it later on, and the `shared_ptr` gets destroyed as it goes out of scope. Question, is the vector I saved "safe" to access?

In the example below, from `main()`, `outer()` is called, and within `outer()`, `inner()` is called. `inner()` creates a `shared_ptr` to an object that contains a `std::vector`, and assigns it to a variable passed by reference. The role of `outer()` is to create some form of seperation, so that we know that the `shared_ptr` is destroyed. In `main()`, this referenced variable is accessed, but is it safe to use this variable?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct sample_compound_obj {
    std::vector<int> vektor;
    sample_compound_obj(){std::cout << "I'm alive!"  << std::endl;};
    ~sample_compound_obj(){std::cout << "Goodbye, thank you forever!"  << std::endl;};
};

bool inner(std::vector<int>& input) {
    std::cout << "About to create sample_compound_obj..."  << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<sample_compound_obj> hehe(new sample_compound_obj);

    hehe->vektor.push_back(1);
    hehe->vektor.push_back(2);
    hehe->vektor.push_back(3);

    input = hehe->vektor;
    std::cout << "About to return from inner()..."  << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool outer(std::vector<int>& input) {
    std::cout << "About to enter inner()..."  << std::endl;
    
    inner(input);

    std::cout << "About to return from outer()..."  << std::endl;

    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "About to enter outer()..."  << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> vector_to_populate;

    outer(vector_to_populate);

    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vector_to_populate.begin(); it != vector_to_populate.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << *it <<std::endl; // <-- is it even "safe" to access this vector
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/47EWfPGK3

To avoid XY problem, I first thought of this issue when I was writing some ROS code, where a subscriber callback passes by reference the incoming message as a `const shared_ptr&`, and the message contains a `std::vector`. In this callback, the `std::vector` is assigned (via `=`) to a global/member variable, to be used some time later, after the end of the callback, so presumably the original `shared_ptr` is destroyed. One big difference is that in my example, I passed the `std::vector` by reference between the functions, instead of a global variable, but I hope it does not alter the behavior. Question is, is the `std::vector` I have "saved", suitable to be used?

Comment: btw the purpose of shared pointer is to keep the managed object alive even when one of the shared pointers is destroyed (as long as one owner is alive)

Comment: As a point-of-style (opinionated), if this code were submitted to me for code review I'd say to get rid of the out-parameter and instead have a return result.  Even if that return result has to also have that `bool`, making it `tuple<bool, optional<vector<int>>>` or perhaps the Boost `result<vector<int>, error_code>`.  (I presume this code is trying to demonstrate the problem.  So... allowances given.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does std::vector in c++ gets deallocated by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68752577/how-does-stdvector-in-c-gets-deallocated-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it safe to use this variable?

Yes, in the below statement, you *copy* the whole `vector` using the [`std::vector::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) overload doing copy assignment. The two `vector`s do not share anything and live their separate lives and can be used independently of each other.

```cpp
input = hehe->vektor;
```

Comment: I've accepted this as solution because it best _pointed_ me to the misconception I held: that the copy constructor for vector did a "shallow" copy instead of a "deep" one. The `shared_ptr` and referencing only obfuscated the core misconception.

Comment: @NaOH not sure what you mean by "shallow" copy here - the copy assignment operator of `std::vector` copies the source object completely, and is supposed to "live" independently with the copied resources after that. It's a deep copy by my definition and can be "shallow" only for classes which have carelessly implemented copy assignment or resource handlers which define special resource owning semantic

Comment: @TheDreamsWind I think the misconception NaOH points out is that he/she thought that the shared pointer somehow made the vector into something that could be shared via a shallow copy. At least that's what I thought when I wrote the answer and the comment seems to confirm that my suspicion was right.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for sorting out my misconception about NaOH's misconception.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's safe, because you get copy of the vector in this line:

```cpp
input = hehe->vektor;
```

> One big difference is that in my example, I passed the std::vector by reference between the functions, instead of a global variable, but I hope it does not alter the behavior.

Any reference can be bound only once, and in your scenario `input` reference is already bound to the argument passed (to be precise `std::vector<int>& input` of `inner` function is bound to `std::vector<int>& input` of `outer` function which itself is bound to `std::vector<int> vector_to_populate`). After a reference is bound, it acts as is object itself, so in the assignment statement you actually end up with calling something like this:

```cpp
input.operator=(hehe->vektor);
```

Where `operator=` refers to the [`std::vector<T>::operator=(const std::vector<T> rhs)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) function.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're familiar with the RAII concept and C++ references, you can pretty much skip the following explanations**

In C++, vectors, and as a matter of fact, pretty much all structs, defined in `std` work very differently from what you might be used to in other higher level languages, like Java or C#. In C++, the [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) (resource acquisition is initialization) technique is used. I highly recommend that you actually read the article, but in short, it means that an object will define a constructor and a destructor, that allocate and free all memory used by the object, in your case, a `std::vector`, and the language is going to call the destructor when the object falls out of scope. This ensures that there are no memory leaks.

However, how would we go about passing a `std::vector` to a function, for example? Well, if we just made a straight up copy of the object, byte by byte, as we'd do in C, the function would run fine, until we reach the end of the function, and we call the destructor of the vector. In that case, after the function executes, when we go back to the caller, the vector is no longer valid, because its data got freed by the callee.

```cpp
void callee(std::vector<int> vec) { }
void caller() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(10);
    callee(vec);
    vec.push_back(10); // This will break, with our current logic
}
```

Well, the keyword here is "copy". We **copied** the vector so that we can pass it in the `callee` function. We can solve this issue by creating custom copy behavior, in C++ terms that would be a copy constructor. In simple terms, a copy constructor takes an instance of the type itself as an argument, and copies it in the current instance. This allows us now to execute the code from above without any issues.

There are a lot more intricacies to it than I've written here, but other people have said it better than I have. In short, whenever you try to make an assignment, or pass an argument, you utilize the copy constructor (with some exceptions). In your case, you assign a vector variable with a vector value. This vector value gets copied, and so is valid until the function goes out of scope. There is a catch to that thou: if you try to modify the vector, you will modify only the copy, not the original. If you want to do so, you'll need to utilize [references](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/passing_parameters_by_references.htm).

In C++, we have the concept of references. You can consider the reference something like a pointer, with some caveats to it. First of all, unlike pointers, you can't have a reference to a reference. The reference tells C++ that you don't work with the object itself, but an "alias" of the object. The object will exist in one place in the memory, but you will be able to access it in two places:

```cpp
int a = 10;
int &ref_a = a;

std::cout << ref_a << ", " << a << "\n"; // 10, 10
ref_a = 5;
std::cout << ref_a << ", " << a << "\n"; // 5, 5
a = 8;
std::cout << ref_a << ", " << a << "\n"; // 8, 8
```

In the line `int &ref_a = a`, we don't actually copy `a`, but we tell `ref_a` that it is a reference of `a`. This means that any operations (including assignment) will be applied to `a`, not to `ref_a`. We can use references with variables, fields, return values and parameters. A reference is valid as long as the value it refers to is valid, so as soon as the value goes out of scope, the reference is no longer valid.

References can be used in parameters, in order to avoid copying the value. This can provide a lot of performance benefits, since we don't need to copy the value, but just pass a "pointer" to it. Of course, this means that if the function modifies the parameter, that is reflected in the caller:

```cpp
void func(int &ref) {
   ref = 5;
}

void func2() {
    int a = 10;
    func(a);
    std::cout << a; // 5
}
```

### TL; DR

In your case, you're returning a vector via an out parameter (reference parameter). Still, even if you're working with references, setting a reference will actually set the object behind the reference, and will use the copy constructor of the object. You can avoid that by making that a reference of a pointer to a vector, but working with pointers in C++ is strongly advised against. Regardless, the answer to your question is that this code is completely safe. Still, if you try to modify `input` in `outer`, you won't modify the vector in `hehe`, but instead you're going to modify the copy that `inener` has created.